# How do i convert the fields of type DateTime to just Date at runtime of an IQueryable of records?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datetime, date, iqueryable

I am in a situation where i need to convert fields with DateTime to a Date (DateTime (2011-01-01 00:00:00 ) to Date ( 2011-01-01 just a string with no time )) before i assign the source to the DataGrid ( without using Binding/Converters ) the collection is an IQueryable but not sure how to do it.

Let me repeat I want the collection to be manipulated even before its assigned to DataGrid Source

can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: `DateTime` is a .NET value type. `Date` is not. Not sure what you're asking for, here. Could you provide example code/data?

Comment: what i mean is DateTime (2011-01-01 00:00:00 ) to Date ( ok say a String like 2011-01-01 )

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just converting a `DateTime` to a string representation, you can use `ToString()` and provide a formatting string:

```cs
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011,01,01);
string dateAsString = date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd");
```

See the MSDN page for [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) to see how to control the format.

You can also do the conversion *while* binding, i.e. bind to a DateTime field, but specify a string format like so (in XAML):

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=YourDateTimeField, StringFormat={}{0:d}"/>
```

If you're asking something else, about binding to an IQueryable, for example, we'll need to see some code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't

```
var myGridData = myCollection.Select(c => new { TheDate = c.MyDate.ToShortDateString(), Field3 = c.SomethingElse, ... });
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

Just format the `DateTime` items accordingly:

```
var results = timeCollection.Select(x => x.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm confused by your question, given that there is no `Date` type in C#. If you're just trying to get a `DataGrid` to display a `DateTime` as a string that has a date format, you'll have to convert it before you bind. Either use a converter or bind against an object that has a pre-formatted date string in that field.

Comment: i want the collection to be manipulated even before its assigned to the DataGrid Source